# Twilio Rest Client using java library throws ConnectionTimeoutException

Tags: java, rest, twilio

I am trying to connect to Twilio Rest webservice using jar twilio-java-sdk-4.4.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar. I am using Client Example as mentioned on the website

```
public class SmsSender {

      /* Find your sid and token at twilio.com/user/account */
    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "AC47e53d";
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "aaea182";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws TwilioRestException {

        TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

        Account account = client.getAccount();

        MessageFactory messageFactory = (MessageFactory) account.getMessageFactory();
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", "+14087478523")); // Replace with a valid phone number for your account.
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "+13122486323")); // Replace with a valid phone number for your account.
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", "Where's Wallace?"));
        Message sms = messageFactory.create(params);
    }
}
```

When I run rest client I am getting

```
ConnectionTimeout exception
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to api.twilio.com:443 timed out.
```

Anyone faced similar issue and can suggest solution?

Comment: HI, Twilio Developer Evangelist here. Are you running behind a proxy or something like that? If you're running locally, are you able to browse to http://api.twilio.com?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for contacting, I am running smsSender class locally as stand alone java program. I am able to browse https://api.twilio.com/

Comment: @MarcosPlacona I see below xml  <TwilioResponse>
<Versions firstpageuri="/?Page=0&PageSize=50" numpages="1" end="1" total="2" previouspageuri="" lastpageuri="/?Page=0&PageSize=50" uri="/" pagesize="50" start="0" nextpageuri="" page="0">
<Version>
<Name>2008-08-01</Name>
<Uri>/2008-08-01</Uri>
<SubresourceUris>
<Accounts>/2008-08-01/Accounts</Accounts>
</SubresourceUris>
</Version>
<Version>
<Name>2010-04-01</Name>
<Uri>/2010-04-01</Uri>
<SubresourceUris>
<Accounts>/2010-04-01/Accounts</Accounts>
</SubresourceUris>
</Version>
</Versions>
</TwilioResponse>

Comment: Then there should be no reason for this not to work for you.... I will get your code and give it a go and get back here.

Comment: Don't need that. Please delete it

Comment: Hey, just tried this and it works as expected. My suggestion is for you to contact help@twilio.com, and they will be able to help you out. likely to be something to do with your internet connection.